# Android: Relative Layout/Bitmap Alpha overwriting

Tags: android, bitmap, android-relativelayout

I try to display a bitmap with a specific alpha. The Bitmap is created in ARGB format, for each pixel I set the color with value 0x04FFAAAA.
The display is made in a class that extends GLSurfaceView (the class name is BitmapView).
I have another class RelativeLayoutBitmap (extends RelativeLayout), that creates and addView BitmapView.

In **screen.xml**
I define a relative layout :

```
 <RelativeLayout
      android:id="id"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="@color/overlay_background">
      <RelativeLayoutBitmap 
        android:id="id_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
 </RelativeLayout>


public RelativeLayoutBitmap(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    internalConstruct(context, attrs);
}

public RelativeLayoutBitmap(Context context) {
    super(context);
    internalConstruct(context, null);
}
private void internalConstruct(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mAttrs = attrs;

    if (null != mBitmapView) {
        this.removeView(mBitmapView);
        mBitmapView = null;
    }

    // create the bitmapview
    mBitmapView = new BitmapView(mContext, mAttrs);
    mBitmapView(getBackground()); //same background for mBitmapView
    
    LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) this.generateDefaultLayoutParams();
    params.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

    mBitmapView.setLayoutParams(params);
    this.addView(mBitmapView, 0);
}
```

Over this relativeLayout, I have a relativeLayout with a background 0x4D000000.
This doesn't work, the Bitmap was displayed, but visible; I hoped the bitmap will be display and not visibile because the alpha of each pixel was 0.015f.
If I hide the relativeLayout over (or set background to be transparent), the bitmap was displayed and not visibile (if I change the alpha of each pixel to 1.0 the Bitmap is visible.).

If in my screen.xml, I include the BitmapView:

```
<RelativeLayout
      android:id="id"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="@color/overlay_background">
      <BitmapView
        android:id="id_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

This works, the Bitmap was displayed and not visible; then if I change the alpha of each pixel to 1.0 the Bitmap is visible.

For my final project, I can't modify the app, the BitmpaView must be included in RelativeLayoutBitmap.

I don't understand why I don't have the comportment I expect when my BitmapView is added in a RelativeLayout.
In RelativeLayoutBitmap, what do I need to set to have the bitmap displayed with the alpha of each pixel?

Comment: Your question is not clear, couldn't understand the issue you are facing. please make your question more understandable

Comment: I modifiy my question, I hope to be more clear.

Comment: I am no expert in bitmaps, but it seems to me that the problem is in the way RelativeLayoutBitmap creates and adds the bitmap; try to add the code for that class too.

Comment: Are you using onDraw in your custom view? If you are using onDraw inside customview you should call setWillNotDraw(false); function when you are extending ViewGroup like RelativeLayout

Comment: @Adinia, I have added the creator of RelativeLayoutBitmap

Comment: @MathankumarK I don't use the onDraw (I will try to used it)

Comment: @MathankumarK I use onDraw, but it's the same

Comment: Where are you changing alpha of the bitmap? it's not there in the code that you have shared

Comment: I change the pixel Value, I replace 0x04FFAAAA by 0xFFFFAAAA